# Can't use docker cp to copy file from /tmp

Tags: docker, docker-cp

When using `docker cp` to move files from my local machine `/tmp/data.txt` to the container, it fails with the error:

> lstat /tmp/data.txt: no such file or directory

The file exists and I can run `stat /tmp/data.txt` and `cat /tmp/data.txt` without any issues.

Even if I create another file in `/tmp` like `data2.txt` I get the exact same error.

But if I create a file outside `/tmp` like in `~/documents` and copy it with `docker cp` it works fine.

I checked out [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) for `docker cp` and it mentions:

> It is not possible to copy certain system files such as resources under /proc, /sys, /dev, tmpfs, and mounts created by the user in the container

but doesn't mention `/tmp` as such a directory.

I'm running on Debian 10, but a friend of mine who is on Ubuntu 20.04 can do it just fine.

We're both using the same version of `docker` (19.03.11).

What could be the cause?

Comment: please, share the `docker cp` command you use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

I had install `docker` as a snap. I uninstalled it (`sudo snap remove docker`) and installed it using the official [Docker guidelines](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) for installing on Debian.

After this, it worked just fine.

I think it might've been due to snap packages having limited access to system resources - but I don't know for sure.